# Adding in support thumbnail removes editor

Tags: post-thumbnails, post-type

I have created a custom post type. And on the custom post type I would like to have a featured image. I have added the featured image to my custom posts however when I do this it removes the main text editor (which you use to add copy to your website). If i remove support thumbnail it brings the text editor back.

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
register_post_type( 'artist',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Talent' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'talent' )
        ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'supports' => array( 'thumbnail' ),
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'talent'),

    )
);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add each individual support you need e.g.

```
'supports' => array('thumbnail', 'title', 'editor'),
```

The title and editor are added by default in a post type but if you add the supports query you need to redefine them back in.